# wordpress display posts from particular category AND tag

Tags: php, wordpress

this must be possible but I haven't been able to find any documentation on it. I'm trying to display posts from a certain category and tag. Like this:

```
if (in category 'featured' and has tag 'gcse') { output 3 most recent posts }
```

This is my lame attempt, which clearly won't work:

```
<?php
get_the_category()
$args = array('tag_slug_' => array('gcse'),category=featured);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<ul>
<li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it...

```
<?php $postsLatest = get_posts('&tag=gcse&category=24&numberposts=3'); foreach($postsLatest as $post) { ?>                  
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>      
    <?php } ?>
```